# How to: Fill a DataGrid.DataContext with information from txt files (C#, WPF)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, datagrid

**How to: Fill a DataGrid.DataContext with information from txt files (C#, WPF)**

I am trying to fill my `DataGrid` with information I get from some txt files. There is a folder called "CONTACTS" and there are some (5) files in. These files are configurated this way:

Content of **John Doe.txt** (without list symbols):

- John Doe Corp.
- Mr.
- Doe
- John

**XAML:**

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserResizeRows="False" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" ItemsSource="{Binding CollectionofDetails}" Name="dataGrid_Content">
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding CorporationName}" Header="Firma" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Prefix}" Header="Anrede" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding FirstName}" Header="Nachname" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding LastName}" Header="Vorname" />
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
```

**C#:**

```
public class Details
    {
        public string CorporationName { get; set; }
        public string Prefix { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<Details> _CollectionofDetails = new ObservableCollection<Details>();

    public ObservableCollection<Details> CollectionofDetails
    {
        get { return _CollectionofDetails; }
        set { _CollectionofDetails = value; }
    }

    public void SetItemsToDataContext()
    {
        foreach (string Datei in Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Users\schwarz\Desktop\Cusposes_2014-05-20_0827\ISAPO\ISAPO Cusposes\Business Contacts\Contacts", "*.txt"))
        {
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(Datei);

            int i = 0;
            string line = reader.ReadToEnd().Replace("\n", "");
            string[] t = line.Split('\r');
            Details d = new Details();
            d.CorporationName = t[i];
            d.Prefix = t[i + 1];
            d.FirstName = t[i + 2];
            d.LastName = t[i + 3];

            CollectionofDetails.Add(d);
            reader.Close();
        }
    }
```

**Unfortunately, I do have the following problems:**

1. I do not know how to load THE CONTENT of each file (for all files).
2. I do not know how to fill my `DataGrid` with this Information.

**--> Solution by Dhaval Patel (see below).**

Comment: Create a 'Contact' class with properties for the data you want to display. Fill a Collection<Contact> with contacts you read from your files. Assign this list to the DataGrid's ItemsSource.

Comment: Thank you, I am going to check that! ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the below mentioned code

Your Xaml Code looks like

```
 <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserResizeRows="False" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" ItemsSource="{Binding CollectionofDetails}" Name="dataGrid_Content">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding CorporationName}" Header="Firma" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Prefix}" Header="Anrede" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding FirstName}" Header="Nachname" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding LastName}" Header="Vorname" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>


 <Button Command="{Binding MyCommand}" Width="100" Margin="346,230,346,-189">RunMyCommand</Button>
```

Your ViewModel code look like

```
 private ObservableCollection<Details> _CollectionofDetails=new ObservableCollection<Details>();

    public ObservableCollection<Details> CollectionofDetails
    {
        get { return _CollectionofDetails; }
        set { _CollectionofDetails = value; RaisePropertyChanged("CollectionofDetails"); }
    }
 private RelayCommand _MyCommand;

    public RelayCommand MyCommand
    {
        get { return _MyCommand??(_MyCommand=new RelayCommand(Methodcall)); }
        set { _MyCommand = value; }
    }
  void Methodcall()
    {

        foreach (string Datei in Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\textfile", "*.txt"))
        {
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(Datei);


            int i=0;
            string line = reader.ReadToEnd().Replace("\n","");
            string[] t = line.Split('\r');
            Details d = new Details();
            d.CorporationName = t[i];
            d.Prefix = t[i + 1];
            d.FirstName = t[i + 2];
            d.LastName = t[i + 3];

            CollectionofDetails.Add(d);
            reader.Close();



        }
    }

public class Details
{
    public string CorporationName { get; set; }
    public string Prefix { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

output should look like

[image]

Comment: Sound very good! Unfortunately `RaisePropertyChanged` and `RelayCommand<object>` are not known. There is an error. Do you know why?

Comment: Model View ViewModel? Just heard about that the first time in my life. What do you mean by 'using'?

Comment: in your application have you used it?

Comment: Do one think remove raisepropertychanged and relaycommand and put Methodtocall method code to your method SetItemsToDataContext

Comment: Okay, I have deleted that and I changed the methods. But it is not working. I am going to edit my code. By the way: I am not using your `Button`, I have an own button that runs the method `SetItemsToDataContext` when I click on it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54024/discussion-between-dhaval-patel-and-exception).

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem that you have to break into pieces. I would recommend that you define a class suitable for your data, like

```
public class Person {

    public string FullName {get; set;}
    public string FirstName {get; set;}
    public string LastName {get; set;}
    public string Title {get; set;}

}
```

and in your viewmodel class you have a variable `PersonList` of type `List<Person>`.

Then your have to write a method, something like

```
private void PopulatePersonData(){

    // Here you put all the logic reading the .txt files creating a person for each file
    // and adding the person to the PersonList.

}
```

which you then call in the constructor of the viewmodel.

Finally you bind the `ItemsSource` of your `DataGrid` to the `PersonList`. That should do it.

Comment: Thank you, I am going to check that! ;)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should really read what is in your txt files.
By using for example a Reader :

```
private void SetItemsToDataContext()
{
    foreach (String Datei in Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Contacts", "*.txt"))
    {
        String[] linesRead = File.ReadAllLines(Datei);
        if (linesRead.Length != 4)
        {
            continue;
        }
        Contact contactRead = new Contact();
        contactRead.Company = linesRead[0];
        contactRead.Gender = linesRead[1];
        contactRead.Name = linesRead[2];
        contactRead.FirstName = linesRead[3];
        dataGrid_Content.Items.Add(contactRead);
    }
}

public class Contact
{
    public String Company { get; set; }
    public String Gender { get; set; }
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public String FirstName { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I am going to check that! ;)